# Struct field name by referencing to a value in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, struct

I am currently working on a struct in MATLAB and have a question regarding this.

Let us say i have declared a struct:
structVariable=struct('abc',[],'cde',[])

i.e. 
structVariable =

```
abc: []
cde: []
```

Further I have a char variable,

charVariable='abc';

Now, I am trying to use structVariable.abc with something like

structVariable.charVariable =5;

but this does not work. Is it possible to reference to the value of charVariable with something like &charVariable as in c++ ?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the easiest way:

```
structVariable.(charVariable) = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the field value:

```
setfield(structVariable,charVariable,5)
```

To get the field value:

```
getfield(structVariable,charVariable)
```

Comment: Note that this only works if `structVariable`  already exists. This may or may not be a good thing but is not exactly mimicking `structVariable.abc`.